# Converting PDF to tiff image does not work with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox 2.0.8 and want to convert a pdf to tiff. This does not work and the following exception occurs

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.media.imageio.plugins.tiff.BaselineTIFFTagSet

at com.github.jaiimageio.impl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageMetadata.parseIFD(TIFFImageMetadata.java:1517)
at com.github.jaiimageio.impl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageMetadata.mergeNativeTree(TIFFImageMetadata.java:1599)
at com.github.jaiimageio.impl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageMetadata.mergeTree(TIFFImageMetadata.java:1623)
at org.apache.pdfbox.tools.imageio.TIFFUtil.updateMetadata(TIFFUtil.java:115)
at org.apache.pdfbox.tools.imageio.ImageIOUtil.writeImage(ImageIOUtil.java:229)
at org.apache.pdfbox.tools.imageio.ImageIOUtil.writeImage(ImageIOUtil.java:146)
at org.apache.pdfbox.tools.imageio.ImageIOUtil.writeImage(ImageIOUtil.java:73)
at de.renderer.core.convert.PDFImageConverter.convert(PDFImageConverter.java:38)
at de.renderer.core.test.convert.PDFImageConverterTest.convertToTiffithDestinationPathAndSuffix(PDFImageConverterTest.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.media.imageio.plugins.tiff.BaselineTIFFTagSet

```
at com.github.jaiimageio.impl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageMetadata.parseIFD(TIFFImageMetadata.java:1517)
...
```

As described on the pdfbox documentation, it requires some additional dependecies to use tiff output, so I added the necessary dependencies to my gradle file

```
testCompile group: 'com.github.jai-imageio', name: 'jai-imageio-core', version: '1.3.1'jpeg2000
testCompile group: 'com.github.jai-imageio', name: 'jai-imageio-jpeg2000', version: '1.3.0'
```

The convertion of the pdf to png, jpg and bmp works.

Here is my method with which I try to convert the pdf to tiff

```
public static List<File> convert(File input, String outputPath, ImageSuffix suffix, int dpi) {

    List<File> convertList = new ArrayList<File>();

    try(PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(input)){
        PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
        for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page)
        {
            BufferedImage bim = null;
            try {
                bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, dpi, ImageType.RGB);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            String outFile = outputPath + "/" + input.getName() + "-" + (page+1) + "." + suffix.name();
            // suffix in filename will be used as the file format
            try {
                if (ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, outFile, dpi)){
                    convertList.add(new File(outputPath));
                }
                else{
                    throw new RuntimeException("could not write image: " + outputPath);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return convertList;
}
```

Here the method call from Junit

```
 List<File> convertResultList = PDFImageConverter.convert(TESTFORM_1_FILE,  buildPath, ImageSuffix.tif, 72);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the full stack trace, not just 2 lines. This would help me make sure that you're really using 2.0.8. The exception message looks strangely familiar...

Comment: Thanks. Weird: ImageIOUtil.java:229 is found in earlier versions and definitively not in 2.0.8. TIFFUtil.java:115 matches in 2.0.8, but also in a version from 2015. Thus I suspect you have an older version. Try a clean build, clean up your class path, and make sure other software (e.g. Tika) isn't using older versions.

Comment: Some background on this bug can be found in https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core/issues/19 , https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1709449 (that was in 2015 and fixed the bug you're having) and https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1802509 (which improved the bugfix).

Comment: I have found a transitiv dependency which includes pdfbox-tools 2.0.0RC1 https://i.imgur.com/74gP9s7.png can this be the problem? Actually i try to exclude them in my build but this seem not to work

Comment: Likely. Get rid of that / find out who needs 2.0.0RC1. Maybe include your entire gradle file.

Comment: Or create a new question that has the gradle label and mentions gradle in the title, but not the pdfbox label. This to attract gradle experts.

Comment: I could solve it by forcing to use the version 2.0.8 of the pdfbox-tools, once that worked the tif has been generated. Here is the gradle configuration, in case someone wants to know                    configurations.all{
    resolutionStrategy{
        force  'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-tools:2.0.8'
    }
}

Comment: Feel free to delete this question or answer it yourself... but I'd also suggest you to find out which dependency wants 2.0.0RC1. You're probably using some old version of something, which puts your project at risk. Try this: https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin  and also this: https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-gradle/ (note that the first run will be very slow).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this problem was a wrong transitiv dependency which uses an old version of the ImageIOUtil class. In a first solution i could fix this by forcing gradle to use the desired version of pdfbox. As Tilman explained, there are better solutions, which I will check later.

Here the gradle configuration change, after this the tif files has been generated.

```
configurations.all{
  resolutionStrategy{
    force  'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-tools:2.0.8'
}
```

}

Comment: Change "ImageIO" to "ImageIOUtil". (Although, to be exact, the bug was in the TIFFUtil class, which is also part of the pdfbox-tools subproject)